# SessionNotCreatedException: robot framework geckodriver windows 10

Tags: exception, windows-10, robotframework, geckodriver

When I am run my test with open browser, this exception occurred:
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities

I have Firefox 73.0 (64 bit);
geckodriver v0.26.0 64 bit and Path to it in Path (system variables);
robot framework 2019.3.3.

geckodriver logs are saved empty after failed tests.

I don't know what can I do to make it work.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
Test to Open Browser
      Open Browser  ${address}  ff
      Maximize Browser Window
```

Comment: Can you post code snippet of your Robot-file?

Comment: @ponkape I updated post.

Comment: This is strange because people facing your problem often have a 32 bits/64 bits problem between Firefox and geckodriver, which does seem to be your case. Would you have some logs to make sure that you are using the correct Firefox and geckodriver? (maybe some other is installed and used)

Comment: How can I verify which driver is used by the framework?

Comment: Remember also to update the Selenium2Library to SeleniumLibrary (https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html). Selenium2Library is no longer supported. Can you also check what is the result of: ``echo %PATH%`` in cmd/Powershell.

Comment: You could also try this: ``Set Environment Variable  webdriver.gecko.driver(name of the driver)  path/to/geckodriver.exe``

Comment: (/usr/lib/firefox/firefox:7209): dconf-WARNING **: 09:38:59.466: Unable to open /var/lib/snapd/desktop/dconf/profile/user: Lack of access
1574757868275 Marionette WARN TimedPromise timed out after 500 ms: stacktrace:
bail@chrome://marionette/content/sync.js:237:64

Comment: 1574757876599 Marionette INFO Stopped listening on port 44265
[Parent 7135, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error (75): lost the connection by the other party: file /build/firefox-clezVp/firefox-70.0.1+build1/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_posix.cc, line 358
JavaScript error: , line 0: UnknownError: The operation failed for reasons unrelated to the database itself and not covered by any other error code.